# Run nmap as if on another host

Tags: nmap

On my main host, I have services running that I only need locally, e.g. MySQL and Apache HTTP Server. I want to make sure they are not accessible from other hosts. When I run `nmap localhost` on my main host, open ports for the above services are displayed as expected. When I run `nmap <main host IP address>` on another host in my local WiFi network, all ports are reported as *ignored*, which is exactly what I want.

It would be convenient if I could perform all scans from my main host, so my question is: Is it possible to run nmap in a way that it displays the scan report as if run on another host a) inside and/or 2) outside of the local network?

If it matters, my OS is Windows 10.

Comment: For example, you can run it from a VM. That'll be *another host* from the networking standpoint. However, you mentioned WiFi, it is not possible to directly bridge wireless interface, so this idea requirest further elaboration.

Answer (score 0):

try to run `nmap` scanner (if you want to run to locally) with network ip address.

If you have services that are only bound to the localhost/127.0.0.1 address, they will only show in a 127.0.0.1 in `nmap` scan results

And otherwise you can try to scan locally to "public" IP, like as 192.168.xxx.xx...

Comment: Using a public IP address 192.168.xxx.xx, a subset of open ports is shown, plus an additional open port for service *netbios-ssn*. What does that mean?

Comment: hi, as I remember it is a 139 port, netbios is a protocol used for file and print sharing

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the host is a Linux machine, you could create a **virtual interface** and run your scanning through that interface. See here for an overview of virtual interface types available in Linux: [Introduction to Linux interfaces for virtual networking](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/10/22/introduction-to-linux-interfaces-for-virtual-networking).

I suggest a pair of veth interfaces and you can also take advantage of namespaces for isolation. I suggest you have a look here for guidance: [How can I port scan a host from itself without using the loopback interface?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/568553/190343)

Pay attention to one point if you automate the setup: some services like SSH may **bind** to all interfaces detected on the system. So your virtual interface should be brought up late enough, after system services are loaded.